# Facebook like button, automatic post to wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I put a like button on my website by following this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

The question is, is it possible to have this like button automatically post to the user's wall after they click it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that.
Basically, If a user push the like button, a short message that says 'a user liked [link]' will be posted to the user's wall.
And, If you use XFBML or HTML5 version code for the like button, a text input dialog will be shown to the user for posting it to the wall.
That's all.

Comment: Oh so it is supposed to post "user liked link". That's exactly what I want it to do, but it isn't showing up on my wall.. hmm

Comment: As I know, the message 'user liked link' is different from 'real' wall post. Priority of that message to be shown by user's friend is very low. It might be shown in the Ticker.
All things behind this is controlled by Facebook.

Comment: Hmm, so that means it might not even show up at all on the user's wall page, but might be hidden somewhere in the ticker.

Comment: I am trying to use the HTML5 version but the pop-up doesn't fit in my view (which is a mobile web app)